# Loading Reuters COM addin automatically with createoleobject into excel 2013

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, excel-2013, comaddin

I am trying to load the Thomson Reuters com addin in a delphi application via the use of createoleobject and having trouble finding the com addins.

```
for i := 1 to Application.comaddins.Count  do
begin
if (Application.comaddins[i].Name = addInReference)  then
    begin
    Application.comaddins[i].installed := false;
    Application.comaddins[i].installed := true;
    end;
end;
```

I now get an error that application.comaddins[i].name is not a valid member where the addins worked correctly. I need help in accessing the comaddins object to ensure the com addin is activated in delphi.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have found that I need to use the application.comaddins and not the addins but I now have an issue with the members inside the comaddins object as a result I have amended my initial question